# Qt signal slot visual studio: doesn't seem to be connected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm learning how to use QT with visual studio. At the moment, I'm using QT 5.8 and vs 2017. I created a new project and added some radiobuttons with QT designer. Now, I want to implemment some actions like "do that when you click the radiobutton". This is my code:

Draw.cpp

```
#include "Draw.h"

#include "qpushbutton.h"
#include "qradiobutton.h"
#include "qgroupbox.h"

Draw::Draw(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    //Invisible elements
    ui.frmAbsolut->setVisible(false);

    //We create the connections to methods
    connect(this->ui.myradiobutton1, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(on_rdbMethod_change(this->ui.myradiobutton1->isChecked, 0)));

}

void Draw::on_rdbMethod_change(bool value, int option)
{
    //0: frmAbsolut
    printf("%d \n", option);
    if (value == true){
        if (option == 0) {
            this->ui.frmAbsolut->setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Draw.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_Draw.h"

class Draw: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Draw(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::DrawClass ui;

protected slots:
    void on_rdbMethod_change(bool, int);

};
```

If I run the program, I don't get any errors and if I check the connect(...) line, I see that is called but when I click that radiobutton, it doesn't call to my method. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> connect(this->ui.myradiobutton1, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(on_rdbMethod_change(this->ui.myradiobutton1->isChecked, 0)));
> ```

The above is incorrect -- if you look at your program's stdout output, you'll probably see that connect() is printing an error message about it.

In particular, you didn't include parentheses after clicked, and also your slot-methods arguments have to be either the same as the signal-method's arguments, or at least the same as the first N of the signal-method's arguments.  In this case, since the signal (clicked()) has no arguments, that means that your slot-method needs to have no arguments as well; so you'll need to either change on_rdbMethod_change() to take no arguments, or specify a different slot-method instead (perhaps that slot-method could be implemented to call on_rdbMethod_change(this->ui.myradiobutton1->isChecked, 0), if that's what you want it to do).  Also, connect() calls can't take values in their SIGNAL/slot arguments list, only types.

So the corrected connect() call would look something like this:

> ```
> connect(this->ui.myradiobutton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_rdbMethod_change()));
> ```

Comment: So if I connect different radiobuttons to this slot, how can I know from on_rdbMethod_change which radiobutton did it call it?

Comment: If you call QObject::sender() ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender ) from within the slot method, it will return a pointer-to-QObject of the QObject that emitted the signal.   You can then downcast that pointer to a QAbstractButton (or whatever) using dynamic_cast<> and compare it to myradiobutton1 (or whatever) to see which button it is.  (Note that this is not considered a good object-oriented design, since it means your slot will probably not do the right thing if ever called from some other context; but as a practical matter it works)

Comment: Or use the new syntax and lambdas and you can forget about `sender()`, runtime errors, and all related annoyances. Then it will just work.